# When creating a guest VM. Virt-Manager does not see the br0 connection

Tags: centos7, kvm-virtualization

Why KVM using virt-manager does not list my bridge interface. I am not using NetworkManager. Should I 
change the name of the physical interface from eth0 to ens5. I am running centOS servers.

Comment: Why do you say that it "does not list my bridge interface"? What are you looking at?

Comment: My problem is that  virt-manager does not have the bridge interface for any new VMs that I want  to create.

Comment: Does the bridge exist? Is it up?

Comment: Michael, It does exist hence this is working with network services. NetworkManager is disable.